# I can´t receive an app transfer on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I´m trying to receive an app transfer on my iTunes Connect account, but I can´t be able to do that, because the form to accept the transfer is throwing me this error:

> The phone number must be in a valid format. Preface the phone number
>   with ‘+’ followed by the country code (for example, +44 844 209 0611)

It is impossible to continue and I don’t know how to get more help.

Comment: I have the same problem, did anyone solve this problem?

Comment: Same here too. I'm from Brazil. Trying to contact iTunesConnect for further info. I'll post here when they answer me.

Comment: In which country do you reside and what number did you enter?

Comment: @emotality Yes, I used +52 for Mexico.

Answer (score 2):

- If you are unable to initiate the transfer after [reading the how-to](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH31-SW1), contact developer support.
- If you don't see that a transfer in has arrived when the sender sees it processed, contact developer support.
- If you have gotten the software to accept the transfer and you just need to wait a day for any bulk processing, then wait a day.

Last resort, https://developer.apple.com/support/